# How to flag a hacker with Device Check

Tags: ios, devicecheck

How can I flag an abuser and potential hacker's device, given the fact that it can only be done if the device sends a token?

We can wait for the user to send a request containing the token, until then act natural so the user won't suspect, then flag the device.

But it is a possible scenario where we spot a bad user, but the user stops the iOS app from sending any token.

How can we flag this user's device?

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer to this question at https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Presumably you have some sort of "session" associated with the device. You would require the device to periodically "check in" with your server to get a confirmation that the device isn't blocked in order to refresh the session. If the check in doesn't happen or the device is blocked then then your server won't renew the session and the app can't continue.